# QTableView: align the icon of the item to top left

Tags: qt, qtableview

I need to draw an icon on the items of a QTableView.

What I'm getting now is the following (each big rectangle is an item):

[image]

with the following code in the method

```
QVariant myClass::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const


   ...
   case Qt::DecorationRole:
   {
      QPixmap pix(m_cellSize, m_cellSize);
      QPainter painter( &pix );
      painter.setFont( QFont("Arial", m_cellSize / 2) );
      painter.setPen(Qt::black);
      painter.drawRect(0, 0, m_cellSize - 1, m_cellSize - 1);
      painter.drawText( QRect(0, 0, m_cellSize, m_cellSize), Qt::AlignTop, QString::number(m_letters[index.row()][index.column()].number) );
      QIcon icon(pix);
      return icon;
   }
   ...
```

I do a drawRect only to see how the pixmap is and where the text is inside it. I can align the text in the pixmap but I cannot align the icon inside the item.
In few words, I need to draw this icon on the top left corner of the table view item but I don't know how to. It's always vertically aligned.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can investigate if changing `Qt::TextAlignmentRole` makes a difference, but my guess is it won't. The usual way to solve this is to implement a custom delegate, i.e subclass `QStyledItemDelegate`, and override the `paint` method. I suspect this might also give better performance, since you could do your custom drawing there, and return you model data in `Qt::DisplayRole` as a `QString` instead.

I'm making a few assumptions in this, but if you look at the examples of custom item delegates I think you will see something very close to what you need.

Comment: Yes, I've already started with a delegate. If I manage to succeed (don't have so much time right now), I accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: OK, a delegate is definitely the way to go as I need to draw more than an aligned icon. I quickly tried and it's working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it's working for you - delegates are not totally straightforward but as soon as you need to do complex drawing it's the best option.